# Ember.js How to show two routes at the same time

Tags: ember.js

I show a product on the website, just like this: `/#/products/1`. The user can open a page at the same time, this page will be on top of the show product. Just like an overlay, a little smaller as the product page. So that you can see a little bit of the product behind it.

I think the url should be: `/#/products/1/page/1`. So the user can share the link of the opened page with the product.

The result is this router:

```
Router.map(function() {

    this.resource(products, function() {   

         this.resource(product, function(path: ':product_id') {  

              this.resource('page', function(path: ':page_id'));

         });
    }); 
});
```

Is this good Ember practice? Or should it be done another way?

Thanks for sharing any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally fine, your doing it a bit wrong, but nested resources is the way to go

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('products', function() {   
         this.resource('product', {path: ':product_id'}, function() {  
              this.resource('page', {path: 'page/:page_id'}, function());
         });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Its all clear now, I am happy that this is definitely the Ember way. I also found some relevant documentation about my question: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources