# Ember.js Cannot find nested route

Tags: ember.js

My application has nested templates. Which will be shown by the router below:

```
this.resource('products', function() { 
    this.resource('product', {path: ':product_id'}, function() {  // Error: There is no route named product
        this.resource('page', {path: 'page/:page_id'});
    });
});
```

Kudos to @kingpin2k for his help on this router: [Ember.js How to show two routes at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903829/ember-js-how-to-show-two-routes-at-the-same-time)

The problem is, *without* the page resource the product route can be found. When I add the page resource the product.index route has now the correct url for the product route as I see in Ember Inspector:

Routes and URL's:

```
`product`       | (empty)
`product.index` | /products/:product_id // this one must be on the above `product` route
`page`          | /products/:product_id/page/:page_id // correct
```

As you can see, the new `product.index` is causing trouble. But the .index variant appears only when I add the page route.

**Edit:** to clearify, with the above router I get the error: `Error: There is no route named product`.
The code that generates that error is in a view:

```
var router = self.get('controller.target.router');
var product = self.get('content').findBy('index', 0);

router.transitionTo('product', product); // Error
```

Comment: If you do `'products`' and `'product'` as strings instead of objects, does it work?

Comment: +1 Excuse that was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you try this

```
var controller = self.get('controller');
var product = self.get('content').findBy('index', 0);

controller.transitionToRoute('product', product);
```